# Writing an algorithm using algorithm2e in LaTeX

Tags: algorithm2e

I am a beginner in writing algorithm in LaTeX using `algorithm2e`. I am trying to write a simple algorithm (code is attached herewith). However, I am not getting correct output. I want to see line numbers. The output is also attached herewith.

Please note that i included the following command in LaTeX preamble too see line numbers

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

There must be something wrong in my code. Is there anyone who can help me execute it correctly?

[image: Output produced]

```
\begin{algorithm} [H]
\caption{QL algorithm}
Initialize Q-table values (Q(s, a)) arbitrarily\
Initialize a state(s_t)\
Repeat Step 4 to 6 until learning period ends\
Choose an action (a_t) for the current state (s_t) using an exploratory policy\
Take action (a_t) and observe the new state (s_t+1) and reward (r_t+1)\
Update Q-value\
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: The problem might only come from the subscripts, which should probably be in math mode.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you would set things up using [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). Specifically, you need line-ends to be denoted by `\;`. Also consider using labels (`\nllabel`) and that you can `\ref`erence.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{QL algorithm}
  Initialize $Q$-table values $(Q(s, a))$ arbitrarily\;
  Initialize a state $(s_t)$\;
  Repeat Steps~\ref{alg:step_4} to~\ref{alg:step_6} until learning period ends\;
  Choose an action $(a_t)$ for the current state $(s_t)$ using an exploratory policy\; \nllabel{alg:step_4}
  Take action $(a_t)$ and observe the new state $(s_t + 1)$ and reward $(r_t + 1)$\;
  Update $Q$-value\; \nllabel{alg:step_6}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```