# How to remove line number from \tcc comments in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e, line-numbering

I am trying to write an algorithm using `algorithm2e`. I have to use `\tcc` comments at different phases of the algorithm. When I am adding `\tcc` comment in the code, in the output, each `\tcc` comments are appearing line-numbered. An example code is as below and the output is also attached herewith.

Can anyone please suggest me, how to remove line numbers from `\tcc` comments. In the image, I highlighted those 2 `\tcc` lines, where I do not want any line number. Rather I want line number starts from "Initialization", that is appearing step 2 instead of step 1 in the output.

[image: output]

```
\begin{algorithm}[H] 
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\tcc{Start of Example 1}
\KwData{this text}  
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }  
initialization\;  
\While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
\tcc{End of Example 1}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/521506/5764) you're using the following [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) options:

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

Remove the `commentsnumbered` option if you don't want the comment lines numbered...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H] 
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
  \tcc{Start of Example 1}
  \KwData{this text}  
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }  
  initialization\;  
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \tcc{End of Example 1}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Werner, thank you. I have one more question. In case of very long algorithm that does not fit in one page, can you please suggest me how to flow the algorithm in next page?  Thank you

Comment: @Stan: The algorithm is contained within a box, and that box doesn't split across the page. You'll have to break it manually and work on manual indentation to line up across the break point. This is because the algorithm is considered a float, and that's how floats are handled. You could consider writing your algorithm in a more compact way, using procedures. Check the [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/algorithm2e) for more details.

Comment: Werner, Thanks for your feedback. Is there any way to set the starting number of line number manually. For example, can i start line number from 15 and then normal count up like 16, 17, 18 so on. Thank you

Comment: @Stan: You can. Can you provide a minimal example that I can use as a starting point?

Comment: Hi Werner, for example, if I want to start line numbering from 21 in the above code, where "Initialization" appeared as Step 1, what I have to do ? I meant, with above code, the line numbers are appearing as 1, 2, 3 so on. But I want it will be 21, 22, 23 .. so on where 21 is the first step. Thank you

Comment: @Stan: *Within* the `algorithm` environment (right at the start), you can `\setcounter{AlgoLine}{<num>}` to whatever `<num>`ber you want. The counter is incremented before every line. So, setting it to `20` (say) will make the first line number be `21`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Werner!